# How to rotate object horizontally in SwiftUI SceneView

Tags: swift, swiftui, scenekit, sceneview

I am loading a 3D object using `SceneView` in SwiftUI:

```
SceneView(
            scene: scene,
            pointOfView: cameraNode,
            options: [.autoenablesDefaultLighting]
        )
```

I have removed `.allowsCameraControl` property from `options` to handle gestures manually. I want to be able to rotate the object horizontally. In UIKit I was able to do so using `UIPanGestureRecognizer` like this:

```
func rotateObject(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    var currentAngleY: Float = 0.0
    guard let nodeToRotate = scene?.rootNode else { return }
    let translation = gesture.translation(in: gesture.view!)
    var newAngleY = (Float)(translation.x) * (Float)(Double.pi) / 180.0
    newAngleY += currentAngleY
    nodeToRotate.eulerAngles.y = newAngleY
    if(gesture.state == .ended) { currentAngleY = newAngleY }
}
```

But in SwiftUI I am not sure how can do it, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

The full story behind the solution you find in this [article](https://betterprogramming.pub/rebuilding-apples-wwdc-2017-demo-app-with-scenekit-and-swiftui-77374c230e28). The code in SwiftUI.

```
Circle()
.fill(Color.white)
.opacity(0.1)
.frame(width: 256, height: 256, alignment: .center)

.gesture(
    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 30, coordinateSpace: .global)
        .onChanged { gesture in
            startWalking.send(gesture.translation)
        }
        .onEnded { _ in
            stopWalking.send(true)
        }
)
```

You can use a drag gesture and a subscription to transfer the information between your sceneView and the SwiftUI interface.